# GIT - Merging Question After Making Changes

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I searched and found many questions and many answers that suggest using the *rebase* command and *fetch* command, but they're not clear.

1. I forked my project. Then I cloned the fork onto my local machine.
2. I updated and submitted a PR with say #100.
3. Let's say your comments came back after two days. Meanwhile, the master got updated. My fork and my local clone are out of sync with the original master.
4. Please advise what I must do to make changes again, after rebasing.

This is what I did, but it did not work:

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/masterproject/projectname.git

git fetch upstream

git pull upstream master

git push
```

When I did the above, many other files are also got pushed to master for review. How can I make sure that only my files are going in?

Comment: Did you submit a pull request to merge the master branch of your fork into the master branch of theirs?

Comment: Master branch of theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> git pull upstream master

You pulled the changes into your branch *on top of* the changes you'd already made. That makes those changes look new to `git`, since the branch has a different version history. What you really want to do is to adjust the history of your own branch to match what's in the remote's master branch, and that's why you need the `rebase` command.

I'm not sure that your description is complete enough that we can tell you *exactly* what you should have done, but the usual thing is something like:

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/masterproject/projectname.git

git fetch upstream

git rebase upstream/master

git push -f origin
```

So you've got the first part right... you've added a remote called `upstream` to your repo, so that you can get changes directly from the remote repo. The `fetch` command basically copies those changes down to your local repo, but they're still associated with the remote repo, not part of your branch.

The next step is the key: you want to *rebase* your branch so that your branch's history, up to the point where you made new changes, matches that of the remote master branch. The rebase command above does that for you... it basically saves your commits somewhere, adds the new commits in master to your branch, and then "replays" the changes in your commits in your branch. That doesn't always go well... sometimes there are conflicts because the new commits from the master branch and your commits both touch the same code. When that happens, you might have to resolve the conflicts by hand before continuing. Either way, when the rebase operation is done, your changes should be the only changes between the current state of the remote master branch and your branch.

Once you've gotten to that point, you need to push up your changes. But you've already pushed your branch, and it has a different version history, so git would normally refuse to accept the push. The `-f` flag indicates the `force` option, which makes git accept the new version of the branch, including it's different version history.

This is all fine to do, *as long as you understand the risks.* If someone else pulled down a copy of your branch from your fork, then their copy of your branch will now have a different version history, and that can get confusing. But for the kind of workflow you're describing, where you probably aren't sharing your fork with other people, you should be fine.